# unable to open 97 Camry door

Tags: camry, door

97 Camry exterior door handle replacement has been difficult and forced me to use the rods to open close / lock door:

[image]

This morning I was able to open the door by reaching around and pushing down on the plastic end of the 'open door' rod.  It turns out pulling on the rod pushes down on the plastic same end.

The door is now stuck closed and I am unable to enter the car from the driver's side.  What can be done to open the release catch and gain entry to the door?

Comment: try rolling down the window and prying the door panel above the lip. use a long thin flat head and smack the lock lever into the unlock position. i'm guessing the lock lever is in a half locked position and just needs to be moved one way or another.